# Select start date and end date form records with subsequent date field in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table in SQL Server 2008 R2 called `ReserveLog`. This is an existing table that stores the reserve date of each room in a complex.

It is like this:

```
RoomNumber ReserveDate
----------------------
1          2017-07-01
1          2017-07-02 
1          2017-07-03
1          2017-07-06
1          2017-07-07
1          2017-07-08
2          2017-01-02
2          2017-01-03
2          2017-01-04
2          2017-01-09
2          2017-01-10
```

I want to query this table so that I get the following result:

```
RoomNumber ReserveStartDate ReserveEndDate
------------------------------------------
1            2017-07-01       2017-07-03
1            2017-07-06       2017-07-08
2            2017-07-02       2017-07-04
2            2017-07-09       2017-07-10
```

Is it possible? I can't make my mind how to do it. Any help is appreciated in advance

Comment: please describe the logic of how those results are generated to save people having to work it out by analysing your data. I can see it seems to group them on consecutive days, but it's better for you to make this clear when asking.

Comment: search 'gaps and islands'. That will get you half way there.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create table #reservs
(
roomnumber INT, ReserveDate DATE
)


INSERT INTO #reservs VALUES (1,          '2017-07-01');
INSERT INTO #reservs VALUES (1,          '2017-07-02');
INSERT INTO #reservs VALUES (1,          '2017-07-03');
INSERT INTO #reservs VALUES (1,          '2017-07-06');
INSERT INTO #reservs VALUES (1,          '2017-07-07');
INSERT INTO #reservs VALUES (1,          '2017-07-08');
INSERT INTO #reservs VALUES (2,          '2017-01-02');
INSERT INTO #reservs VALUES (2,          '2017-01-03');
INSERT INTO #reservs VALUES (2,          '2017-01-04');
INSERT INTO #reservs VALUES (2,          '2017-01-09');
INSERT INTO #reservs VALUES (2,          '2017-01-10');

select roomnumber, MIN(reservedate) as mn, MAX(reservedate) as mx
FROM (
SELECT *
, DATEDIFF(day, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by roomnumber order by reservedate) ,reservedate) as ind
 FROM #reservs
) a
group by roomnumber, ind
order by 1, 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this using common table expressions, comments in line and SQL Fiddle link:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/67b6d/2)

```
create table Reservelog
(
    RoomNumber INT,
    ReserveDate Date
)

INSERT INTO ReserveLog
VALUES
    (1, '2017-07-01'),
    (1, '2017-07-02'), 
    (1, '2017-07-03'),
    (1, '2017-07-06'),
    (1, '2017-07-07'),
    (1, '2017-07-08'),
    (2, '2017-01-02'),
    (2, '2017-01-03'),
    (2, '2017-01-04'),
    (2, '2017-01-09'),
    (2, '2017-01-10')
```

**Query 1**:

```
;WITH CTE
As
(
SELECT *, 
    (
      -- Get Previous Reserve Date for this room
      SELECT TOP 1 ReserveDate 
      FROM ReserveLog R2 
      WHERE R1.RoomNumber = R2.RoomNumber AND 
            R1.ReserveDate > R2.ReserveDate 
      ORDER BY ReserveDate DESC
    ) As PrevReserveDate,
    (
      -- Get NExt ReserveDate For this room
      SELECT TOP 1 ReserveDate 
      FROM ReserveLog R2 
      WHERE R1.RoomNumber = R2.RoomNumber AND 
            R1.ReserveDate < R2.ReserveDate 
      ORDER BY ReserveDate
    ) As NextReserveDate
FROM ReserveLog R1
),
CTE2
AS
(
    SELECT *,
        CASE             
            WHEN PrevReserveDate IS NULL OR 
                  DATEDIFF(D, PrevReserveDate, ReserveDate ) > 1 
            THEN 1 -- Flag as a StartDate 
            ELSE 0 
        END As DateStart,
        CASE 
          WHEN NextReserveDate IS NULL OR 
              DATEDIFF(D, ReserveDate, NExtReserveDate) > 1 
          THEN 1  -- Flag as an end date
          ELSE 0 
        END As DateEnd,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
          (PARTITION BY RoomNumber ORDER BY ReserveDate) AS RN
    FROM CTE
    -- only select rows which have no previous or next reservation or 
    -- ones where the difference between consecutive reservations > 1 day
    WHERE PrevReserveDate IS NULL OR 
          NextReserveDate IS NULL OR 
          DATEDIFF(D, PrevReserveDate, ReserveDate ) > 1 OR 
          DATEDIFF(D, ReserveDate, NExtReserveDate) > 1
)
  SELECT startRows.RoomNumber, 
        startRows.ReserveDate As ReserveStartDate, 
        endRows.ReserveDate As ReserveEndDate
FROM CTE2 startRows
INNER JOIN  CTE2 endRows
    ON startRows.RN + 1 = endRows.RN  AND 
      startRows.RoomNumber = endRows.RoomNumber AND 
      endRows.DateEnd = 1
WHERE startRows.DateStart = 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/67b6d/2/0)**:

```
| RoomNumber | ReserveStartDate | ReserveEndDate |
|------------|------------------|----------------|
|          1 |       2017-07-01 |     2017-07-03 |
|          1 |       2017-07-06 |     2017-07-08 |
|          2 |       2017-01-02 |     2017-01-04 |
|          2 |       2017-01-09 |     2017-01-10 |
```

Answer (score -3):

Use this query:

```
SELECT * FROM R2 WHERE ReserveDate between ('2017-07-01 ' AND '2017-07-03');
```

Comment: and how exactly would that get the desired results?

Comment: you have execute this one then return   
1            2017-07-01       2017-07-03